# how to make geofencing in google maps with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have created basic geo fencing i have added 2 markers and one circle in that map . i was trying to show if marker is out of the circle marker should visible in different color , so that we can understand object is out of geofence. how to change the color of marker or show different marker when marker is out of circle.LatLng1 is out of circle so i need to show Latlng1 in out of circle.

js fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/aoe4vf17/43/

code

```
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width:1400px;height:800px"></div>
        <script>
            function toggleBounce() {
                alert("Asset 1");
                if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
                    marker.setAnimation(null);
                } else {
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                }
            }
            function initMap() {
                var myLatLng = {  lat:17.446399, lng:78.383349};
                var myLatLng1 = { lat: 17.428888, lng: 78.384444 };

                var citymap = {
                    hyderabad: {
                        center: { lat: 17.446507, lng: 78.383033 },
                        population: 2714856
                    }
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 18,
                center: myLatLng,
                });
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: myLatLng1
                });
  var image = "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Asset 1',
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

            });
            marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng1,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!',
             icon:image
        });

            for (var city in citymap) {
                // Add the circle for this city to the map.
                var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    strokeColor: '#ffb3b3',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: '#ffb3b3',
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,
                    map: map,
                    center: citymap[city].center,
                    radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 1
                });
            }
          }
        </script>
        <script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDci4vYApOxVdKqwlpXSv9h77AcWbNuzmQ&callback=initMap">
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the concepts you have to know:

1. Adding [event listeners to a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events).
2. Using [getBounds().contains](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Here's the [full working code](https://jsfiddle.net/aoe4vf17/54/). When you drop the marker outside the circle, it will change it's icon. When you place it back inside the circle, it will go back to it's default icon image.

The important bits I added were the logic and the listener:

```
          marker.addListener('dragend', function() {
            if( cityCircle.getBounds().contains( marker.getPosition()) == false ){

               marker.setIcon(iconBase + 'library_maps.png');
            }else{
               marker.setIcon("");
            }
```

Comment: your shared link (full working code) may be wrong. im not getting any change in that link.btw i worked on that code and faced new challenges
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077395/how-to-add-drawing-tool-in-geofencing-in-google-maps
can u see this once

Comment: Try the link again : ) Drop the marker outside the circle. Then, put it back again.

Comment: yes working fine but i need this when a page loads, not when we manually drag it. sorry for change in my question

Comment: this is the answer to this question. open another one

Comment: yes that code working when we drag the marker out of the fence its showing different image but that i want in page load. i want to track the resources automatically.when the marker is out of fence it should automatically change the image not buy dragging manually

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064260/alerts-are-not-showing-in-geofencing-when-marker-is-outside-of-polygon-geofence/43066995?noredirect=1#comment73240472_43066995

Comment: Here yo go, observe the marker. tweak your marker langlat
https://jsfiddle.net/aoe4vf17/71/  
The original LngLat was   var myLatLng = { lat: 17.446399, lng: 78.4140000};